# jQuery AJAX using fadeIn + replaceWith

Tags: jquery, hide, fadein, replacewith

There are several q & a's on SO on this but I found none that address my issue. And I'm stumped with this. Please redirect me to a link if you know of an available answer to this.

My page has an empty `DIV #posts_insert` in which new posts are inserted via Ajax.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'chat/posts_submit/' + <?php echo $page_id; ?>,
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#posts_form').serialize(),
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(html) {
            $('#posts_insert').replaceWith(html);
        }
    });
```

I want that new post to fade in, replacing `#posts_insert`. I've tried several iterations on `success` using `hide()`prior to `fadeIn` but I just can't make this work.

Any ideas how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try this $('#posts_insert').replaceWith(html).fadeIn('slow')

Answer (score 11):

How about:

```
$("#posts_insert").replaceWith(function() {
    return $(html).hide().fadeIn();
});
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/jTLn5/

Comment: thx @andrew, you fiddle is very nice -- for some reason again i get an error like @eric -- the full msg is `uncaught exception: [Exception... "Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMViewCSS.getComputedStyle]" nsresult: "0x80570009 (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS)" location: "JS frame :: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 16" data: no]`

Comment: @torr: Hmm, maybe there's something strange in the HTML you're trying to use with `replaceWith()`? Do you get that error when you just use `.html()`?

Comment: @andrew - yes it happens with `.html()` as well - the HTML that generates the new post has no JS, only PHP and HTML

Comment: @torr: I would check for missing tags, etc. maybe run the HTML you get back from the server through a validator.

Comment: That solution doesn't fade out the original content

Comment: @Eric: The question never mentions fading the old content out.

Comment: @Andrew: The original phrasing is ambiguous. Just thought I'd point out the distinction to the OP

Comment: the old content doesn't need to fade out -- each post is in a separate div and new post is inserted atop the older posts, within `#posts_insert`, so older posts are pushed downwards -- all I want is that the new post fade in instead of just popping in place

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'chat/posts_submit/' + <?php echo $page_id; ?>,
    type: 'POST',
    data: $('#posts_form').serialize(),
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(html) {
        var newContent = $(html);
        $('#posts_insert').fadeOut(function() {
            $(this).replaceWith(newContent.hide());
            newContent.fadeIn();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: thx @eric - this one is returning an `uncaught exception` error that keeps looping non stop

Answer (score -1):

you could try:

```
success: function(html) {
   var $container = $('#posts_insert').parent();
   $container.fadeOut('fast', function() {
      $('#posts_insert').replaceWith(html);
      $container.fadeIn();
   });
}
```

might give you the effect you're looking for.

EDIT:
Why don't you put a container around the (#posts_insert), fade that out, replaceWith(), and fadeIn the container?

Comment: `replaceWith` returns the original element. So that will fade in the `#posts_insert` element, not the just-retrieved html.

Comment: unfortunately doesn't work -- the end result is the same my original code - thx for the suggestion